# Running a java program or service from oracle 11.2

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to write a java file watcher service that monitors a set of registered files. And the file watcher need to be run as a process or service in oracle. I know there is an **Oracle file watcher** that can be used, but i want to know if its possible to run a java program as a process from oracle.

I'm quite new to Oracle and pl/sql. I was able to call java methods (stored procedures) from oracle, all the calls are stateless, where as in the file watcher service i need to add register new files and remove files from the service.

is this possible to be executed in oracle? has anyone tried anything like this before.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html):

> A watch service that watches registered objects for changes and
>   events. For example a file manager may use a watch service to monitor
>   a directory for changes so that it can update its display of the list
>   of files when files are created or deleted.

Comment: Thanks, im aware of the WatchService, but i'm using apache.Commons.vfs for my filemonitor. its working fine as a java application. My problem is i want to run the application from oracle, and not as a store procedure call.

Comment: What do you mean by : "i want to run the application from oracle"?

Comment: Run it similar to a windows service

Comment: Write a java program. Make it jar. Start jar as a service. Is this a right scenario for your case?

Comment: It seems that Oracle made it for basic Java usage only, which means JDBC/SQLJ.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically something like this can be possible, but I do not believe that pros will overweight cons. Also it will be quite hard to find any examples. Some specific features of Oracle Database JVM are described here:

[Threading in Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/java.121/e17658/chtwo.htm#JJDEV13147)